# Facebook Graph API - Make Post with Emoticons/Emoji

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a post request to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/feed?message=Test post`.

This actually works fine, but I want the ability to add emoticons to my post. I have been using the list found here: http://fbicons.net/

The text for most of these emoticons just shows up as a box, something like this:

Copying and pasting these directly into Facebook will actually work, and the emoticon will show up. However, when I copied this into my code and posted via API, it showed up on Facebook as `? ?`.

I'm pretty sure I need to send a unicode value through the API but not sure how. Could anyone provide an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of Emoji html entity from [here](https://websitebuilders.com/tools/html-codes/emoticons/)

```
$emoji = html_entity_decode('&#128520;');
```

This codes works fine, tried posted via Graph Api. Thanks @hellohellosharp

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by copying the box `✨` character into a .txt document. I then used `$emoji=file_get_contents("emoji.txt");` The $emoji variable could now be posted to facebook.

**EDIT**: Proper method:

`$dislikeEmoji=html_entity_decode('&#128078;')`

Comment: Thanks, the `html_entity_decode` solved it for me! :)